# Missing data in certain columns in pandas dataframe when importing data from a file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xml, dataframe, parsing

I have **large** `XML` file (1.5gb) which imported into a `pandas` dataframe

```
df = pd.read_xml('abc.xml')
```

the data is imported *without any errors or even warnings* but **data in certain columns are empty**. When check the data manually or using `grep` all entires has data in that column.

How i deal with this?

The following is some of the lines of the `XML` file
The column which are returning empty are actor-interaction, sequence, producer-interactions and external-identifiers

```
<film type="movie" created="2005-06-13" updated="2021-10-03">
  <moviebank-id primary="true">MV00001</moviebank-id>
  <moviebank-id>MVD00024</moviebank-id>
  <moviebank-id>MVOD00024</moviebank-id>
  <name>Thor</name>
  <description>Thor is a action movie </description>
  <groups>
    <group>Marvel</group>
  </groups>
  <general-references>
    <articles>
      <article>
        <ref-id>A1</ref-id>
        <news-id>16244762</news-id>
        <citation>times, Page 6 2022.</citation>
      </article>
      <article>
        <ref-id>A2</ref-id>
        <news-id>16690967</news-id>
        <citation>hindu, page 18 2022.</citation>
      </article>
      <article>
        <ref-id>A3</ref-id>
        <news-id>16241940</news-id>
        <citation>today, ebuzz, page 2 2022.</citation>
      </article>
    </articles>
  <producer-interactions>
    <producer-interaction>It is an excellent movie</producer-interaction>
  </producer-interactions>
  <actor-interactions>
    <actor-interaction>
      <moviebank-id>MV06605</moviebank-id>
      <name>Tom</name>
      <description>It is great movie.</description>
    </actor-interaction>
    <actor-interaction>
      <moviebank-id>MV06695</moviebank-id>
      <name>Mark</name>
      <description>I will watch it today.</description>
    </actor-interaction>
    <actor-interaction>
      <moviebank-id>MV01254</moviebank-id>
      <name>Rob</name>
      <description>A must watch.</description>
    </actor-interaction>
    <actor-interaction>
      <moviebank-id>MV01609</moviebank-id>
      <name>Maxx</name>
      <description>marvel fans must watch.</description>
    </actor-interaction>
    <actor-interaction>
      <moviebank-id>MV01586</moviebank-id>
      <name>John doe</name>
      <description>Will watch more then once.</description>
    </actor-interaction>
  </actor-interactions>
  <sequences>
    <sequence format="IMAX">&gt;MV00001 sequence
ABIYVIUBPOINOUBHEPUIBIUBIUBFIUBEIFUB
EEYLQ</sequence>
  </sequences>
  <external-identifiers>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>News paper agncy (NPA)</resource>
      <identifier>1EG16</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>E Buzz</resource>
      <identifier>4650984</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
    <external-identifier>
      <resource>The magazine</resource>
      <identifier>MV6880</identifier>
    </external-identifier>
  </external-identifiers>
  <casting>
    <cast>
      <actor-id>ACT0000278</actor-id>
      <name>Tom</name>
      <category>Drama</category>
      <other movies>
        <movie>
          <moviebank-id>DB00001</moviebank-id>
          <name>Few good men</name>
        </movie>
        <movie>
          <moviebank-id>MV01022</moviebank-id>
          <name>top gun</name>
        </movie>
        <movie>
          <moviebank-id>MV01373</moviebank-id>
          <name>mummy</name>
        </movie>
      </other movies>
      <acting>
        <cast-id>ACT734</cast-id>
        <cast-id>ACT748</cast-id>
        <cast-id>ACT452</cast-id>
        <cast-id>ACT952</cast-id>
      </acting>
    </cast>
  </casting>
  </moviebank>
</film>
```

***UPDATE:***

I have noticed that these missing data **happens only** in those columns which has multiple sub-child elements for example `<actor-interactions>` has multiple sub-child elements `<actor-interaction>` similarly `<external-identifiers>` has `<external-identifier>`

Does this pattern help in identifying the problem?
Thank you

Thank you for your time
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: When you say "almost all entires has data" it sounds to me like some of them don't have data, which would then explain why there is missing data. Am I getting that right?

Comment: @OferSadan, Thank you for your response. I just went though the file. The data is there in those columns since it was a 1.5gb file i wrote it as 'almost'. Moreover it is returning empty coumns with the header, even if there are few missing data in certain entries shouldn't those data be printed in the column? Thanks